# Why docker-compose work locally and don't in amazon ecs?

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to undersatnd how to use an aws ecs service and cannot understand the reason of failing docker-compose which working as expected locally but fails during creating using docker context ecs? Images source is ecr. All creds are set and if for example create ecs task which contains single default nginx image also ecs worked as expected. I've tryed launch types Fargate and EC2.

My commands set to run docker-compose.yml in ecs context:

```
docker context create ecs temp
docker context use temp
docker compose -p "temp" up
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
    reverseproxy:
        image: XXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/nginx:latest
        ports:
            - 80:80
            - 8081:8081
            - 8082:8082
        restart: always
 
    apache:
        depends_on:
            - reverseproxy
        # networks:
        #     - bridge-network
        image: XXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/apache:latest
        restart: always

    blue:
        depends_on:
            - reverseproxy
        # networks:
        #     - bridge-network
        image: XXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/blue:latest
        restart: always
```

Dockerfiles for
nginx

```
worker_processes 1;
 
events { worker_connections 1024; }
 
http {  
 
    sendfile on;
 
    upstream docker-apache {
        server apache:80;
    }

    upstream docker-nginx-balancing {
        server test:80;
    }

    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
 
    server {
        listen 8081;

        server_name XXX.sytes.net;
 
        location / {
            proxy_pass         http://docker-apache;
            proxy_redirect     off;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 8082;

        server_name XXX.sytes.net;
 
        location / {
            proxy_pass         http://docker-nginx-balancing;
            proxy_redirect     off;
        }
    }
 
    server {

        root /var/www/html;
        index index.html;

        server_name XXX.sytes.net;
        
        location = /youtube {
            return 301 https://www.youtube.com;           
        }
    }
}
```

test:

```
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    server {

        root /var/www/html;
        index index.html;

        server_name XXX.sytes.net;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
    }
}
```

Dockerfile for nginx:

```
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
EXPOSE 80/tcp
STOPSIGNAL SIGQUIT
CMD ["/usr/sbin/nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

apache

```
FROM 8ct8pus/apache-php-fpm-alpine:1.4.3
CMD ["apachectl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

test

```
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
CMD ["/usr/sbin/nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Comment: You haven't specified a single thing in your question about what isn't working. Please edit your question to describe exactly what errors or unexpected behavior you are seeing, including any log messages.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you create `docker context` on your machine or Linux machine, it won't work on ECS as you expected.

You can locally test your docker compose app on your own, then
You can deploy your application on ECS along with `docker-compose.yml` as you know.

However, you're missing one important thing here that you need to specifiy parameters in `ecs-params.yml` file that creates the task definition in order to run your ECS service.

See ECS parameters' options on ecs-cli [README.md](https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-cli#using-ecs-parameters).

This README file indicates you how to write `ecs-params.yml` with example just like below:

```
version: 1
task_definition:
  ecs_network_mode: host
  task_role_arn: myCustomRole
  services:
    logging:
      essential: false
    wordpress:
      cpu_shares: 100
      mem_limit: 500m
    mysql:
      cpu_shares: 105
      mem_limit: 500m
      mem_reservation: 450m
  docker_volumes:
    - name: database_volume
      scope: shared
      autoprovision: true
      driver: local
```

I deployed my application with docker compose using `ecs-cli` command, which gives you the same command as you can use as composing your own docker-compose file.

For instance, simply the project directory looks like

```
.
├── Jenkinsfile
├── my-app-front     # Contains Dockerfile
├── my-app-backend   # Contains Dockerfile
├── docker-compose.yml
├── ecs-params.yml
└── package-lock.json
```

Then you can deploy your app using `ecs-cli` command in the following order:

you can find ecs-cli command details in the GitHub [README.md](https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-cli#using-ecs-parameters) file

- `cli configure`
- `ecs-cli configure profile`
- `docker compose -f docker-compose.yml build  --no-cache`
- `ecs-cli push {your-ECR-repo-url}`
- `ecs-cli up`
- `ecs-cli compose service up`

Plus: I specified all command in Jenkinsfile steps, so once you push your code, the Git hook will trigger my Jenkins job so it's smoothly deploys into ECR as well as provision ECS service.